# How to draw cells of layouts and their edges in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt, layout-manager

In Swing(also AWT), `LayoutManager`s determine the size and position of the `Component`s within a `Container` without drawing edges and lines...

for some educational goals, how to draw these lines?(e.g. overriding `paintComponents()` of `Container` class and so on...)

A solution is calculating everything according to the rules of each layout to obtain the coordinates, but is there a way to use the layouts themselves to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the requirement or the question. But you might add each component to t bordered container before adding it to the container. And by 'bordered' I mean a visible border like a `LineBorder` with a non-transparent color. As to why to add them to a container first, that is because some components (e.g. buttons) already have a border - which might itself change depending on user actions (like the component having the input focus).

Comment: An alternate strategy (suitable for opaque components only) is to give the parent container a distinct color and the layout some padding between the different areas of the components. I expect this will be practical with some layouts but not others.

Comment: @AndrewThompson tnx for your edit and your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a loop, if you want all your components to have a border. the following method will draw a border for all *Swing* components (`JComponent`s, actually) that are in the `JFrame`'s content pane:

```
Container cont = frame.getContentPane();

Component[] components = cont.getComponents();
List<JComponent> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (Component comp : components) {
    if (comp instanceof JComponent) {
        list.add((JComponent) comp);
    }
}
for (JComponent jComponent : list) {
    jComponent.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black,2));
}
```

This is what you get (ignore the menubar, it's from a previous question):

[image: output]